# Detect multiple touches in Ionic/Android WebView

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, touch, ionic-framework

In an ionic app, I am watching the `on-swipe-right` directive to implement a "Back" feature.

```
doctype html5
html(lang='en', ng-app='my-app')
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge,chrome=1')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1')

//- snip

  body(
    ng-controller="DoloresMainCtrl"
    on-swipe-right="toMainScreen($event)"
  )
    ion-nav-view
```

And in the controller

```
angular.module('my-app', [
    'ui.router'
])
.controller 'DoloresMainCtrl', ($scope, $state)->
    $scope.toMainScreen = ($event)->
        $state.go '^' if $event?.gesture?.touches?.length is 2
```

The event fires just fine, but `$event.gesture.touches.length` is always `1`.

What do I need to set to get ionic to detect multiple touches?

(Constraints: Android 4.4+, iOS 8+)

Comment: I'm also interested in the answer to this question. Ionic uses a fork of hammer.js for touch events, and in hammer.js it is possible to detect multiple touches, so why not in Ionic?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example that can detect multiple touch points for tap events. The touchstart of the points have to be very simultaneous to count as multi-tap. Otherwise they are perceived as two  sequential taps.

```
angular.module('my-app', ['ui.router'])
    .directive('multiTap', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.text('this is the multi-tap directive');
                var tap = ionic.onGesture("tap", handler, element[0]);
                function handler(e) { console.log(e);
                    element.text(e.type + e.gesture.touches.length);
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

HTML example:

```
<ion-content class="padding" multi-tap>
```

Comment: Not ignoring your answer, just busy with other things!